# Black screen after Xorg edger ppa

Tags: drivers, ati, 14.10

I recently added the Xorg edger PPA to my Ubuntu 14.10 sources list and here's what happened after I did.

1. Added the PPA repository to my list
2. did a `sudo apt-get upgrade` for the drivers to download
3. rebooted my system  and faced a black screen

Is there anyway to fix this without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ppa-purge` removes the PPA and downgrades the packages:

1. Start the rescue mode in GRUB
2. Start the network
3. Start the root shell
4. Run `apt-get install ppa-purge`
5. Run `ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`
6. Run `exit`
7. Reboot

Comment: Do I need to also do anything else after the purge command?

Comment: No, nothing. The command removes the PPA and downgrades the packages.

Comment: Alright, I also did a distro upgrade command, will that affect anything as well, sorry I'm asking a lot of questions, kinda in a worried/panicked mode at this point.

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` upgrades all upgradable packages.`ppa-purge` downgrade only the packages that are included in the PPA to be removed.

Comment: Do I need internet to downgrade?

Comment: No, if `ppa-purge` is installed.

Comment: then you can skip point two and four.

Comment: I'm running stock Ubuntu 14.10, should it be preinstalled?

Comment: I don't know. Try it. If not, you can install it. You can start the network  by a menu item in the recovery mode.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help, I'll try this when I get home tonight.

Comment: Alright, I'm back but I got into live USB to mount my root partition to install ppa-purge because I couldn't in root terminal but I'm now getting a unmet dependencies error now from fglrx, now what do I need to do to satisfy these?

Comment: As you install the `ppa-purge` in a live system?

Comment: Is your system bootable? Can you switch in to TTY1 with Ctrl-Alt-F1?

Comment: Bootable yes, TTY1 no, because the drivers freeze the screen but the system is still running, but I can mount my root partition in Live USB mode but im getting the following after I try to install ppa-purge `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).` and after I do what terminal says then I get this `/var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-core_2%3a14.201-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: How did you mount the partition?

Comment: And why could you not start the rescue mode?

Comment: I mounted it with `sudo mount ROOT-PARTITION /mnt` then the mount points `/sys /proc /run /dev /dev/pts` then `sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/` then finally switching to root with `sudo chroot /mnt`. it acts like I'm right in root terminal with internet from live usb. But the rescue mode would freeze too without `radeonhd.modeset=0` but it rarly worked.

Comment: Install `aptitude`: `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Comment: oh, i have that already installed before the crash.

Comment: Start the program and look at the suggestions, looking for the red line.

Comment: And remove all files in `/var/cache/apt/archives` before

Comment: Loaded it up and no red line found in termainal with aptitude.

Comment: Install ppa-purge with `sudo aptitude install ppa-purge`

Comment: Have you removed all deb files in `/var/cache/apt/archives`

Comment: No, i have not. But i did that command to purge it and `root@ubuntu:/# sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
Updating packages lists
Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/skulltag.net_download_files_release_deb_dists_jaunty_InRelease into data and signature failedE: GPG error: http://skulltag.net jaunty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason`

Comment: jaunty? skulltag.net?

Comment: remove all files in `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/`, thats no proplem I tested

Comment: That's done, removed all files in said directory. But I now reboot to a black screen still

Comment: Reboot? Why that?

Comment: I thought it was necessary after the PPA purge.

Comment: But ppa-purge failed or not?

Comment: Terminal said 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 62 downgraded, 2 to remove and 3 not upgraded. That good?

Comment: ok, and a `sudo aptitude update` and `sudo aptitude upgrade`

Comment: Alright, doing both, reboot afterwards?

Comment: Let's try it. :)

Comment: OMG, that worked, I'm back on my desktop, it removed my drivers but ill reinstall them, Thank you so much @A.B.

Comment: You would not believe how happy I am now. :)

Comment: Well, again Thanks, at this point I would have gave up and reinstalled Ubuntu 14.10 thinking there was no fix. :)

Comment: Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)